# Kotlin Android Project failed to sync Gradle Project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin

I created an Android project with the newest Android Studio version (v2 Preview 5) and converted it into a kotlin project. Now gradle is not able to sync and build the project, see the screenshot:
[image]

I didn't do anything to any build file and I also deleted my entire gradle cache as well as restarting, killing daemons etc. I used the newest kotlin version `1.0.0-beta-4584`

As the error message suggest I guess the reason is the kotlin plugin, so does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The kotlin gradle plugin is not compatible with the latest alpha plugin of android (`2.0.0-alpha6`) or `alpha5` for that matter.

Until this is the case, you can use `2.0.0-alpha3` instead.

Comment: You can now upgrade to kotlin version `1.0.0-beta-4589` which works with `2.0.0-alpha5` and `2.0.0-alpha6`